# Matching video background to page background

Tags: javascript, css, html, html5-video

I have a video playing inline with an orange background and would like to make it seamlessly merge with the body css background. Unfortunately the video color always stands out depending on browser or the monitor color profile. Any idea how to achieve this?

I tried 3 solutions till now:

1. Hardcoding the background color for each browser. This works on the same machine but when using a different monitor with a different color profile, it falis.
2. I took the first video frame and placed it into a canvas. Then i took the background color from canvas and applied it to the body. This works everywhere except for safari.
3. Instead of having a css background color, i used a second video with the same background and stretched it to match the page size (so it's under the first video and acts like a background). Also works everywhere except safari.

Is there anything i'm missing? Any other ideas? Any clues on why almost everything i try fails on safari?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Achieving Colour Consistency Across Different Monitors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2257759/achieving-colour-consistency-across-different-monitors)

Comment: Have you tried to render the whole video into a canvas for every device? Will there still be a difference in colour? It can't be very performant since the CPU needs to do the decoding, but the result might be more unique?

Comment: Almost two years later i'm working on the same project. It's been a rollercoaster ride and along the way i gave up on making it match. Depending on browser and platform, software updates changed the matching matrix over time. Videos with the same encoding now work on safari but no longer match on chrome on Mac - initially it was the other way around. The canvas approach you mentioned seems to be the best option but i can't remember why i didn't opt for it back then - probably performance on lower end devices (tablets and such).

Comment: I can confirm the Safari exception for method 2. Now you see a difference in other browsers for this method? http://test.crafft.ch/video-color-test.html

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, this can be caused by hardware acceleration decoding the video. To confirm if this is the issue in your case, you can temporarily disable HA in your browser.

In Chrome, paste this into the address bar

```
chrome://flags/#disable-accelerated-video-decode
```

In Internet Explorer, there is a setting in Internet Options > Advanced called **Use software rendering instead of GPU rendering**

Unfortunately I was able to find a solution for the issue in my case, since we have precious little control over this part of a visitor's configuration. In our case we settled on a design that didn't involve a seamless merge between a video background and an html element's background.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to find out the different colours that all browser/player/platform combinations produce (neither beforehand, nor during runtime).

So the only workaround I can think of is to use the video as the entire background and include sufficient white-space in the video.

One example with CSS3 to make the video cover your container:

```
.container {
  position: relative;
}
.background-video {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

To have more control of the position and size of the video's center (focal point), you'll need to replace [`object-fit`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit) with your own positioning rules.

Video weight (MB) won't grow much, since the background is a solid colour and doesn't change from frame to frame.